# After a value in an array, start to calculate in another way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, trigonometry

I need to calculate the variation of an angle and store in an array and I have the problem below:
The angle increases its value through calculations and when the value of the angle is better than 90°, python starts to pic the suplementary value, not the continuation, something like this:

Undesirable way (and that's ocurring):
23.45°, 26.7°,..., 84.5°, 88.33°, 85°, 82.3° ...

Desirable way:
23.45°, 26.7°,..., 84.5°, 88.33°, 91.2°, 94.7° ...

My code is:

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np

l = 85
s = 170
q = 30.07
p = 120

theta = (3.81*np.pi)/180
alfa = np.linspace((104.07*np.pi)/180, (26.19*np.pi)/180, 40)

d = np.sqrt(s**2 + q**2 - 2*s*q*np.cos(alfa))
gama = np.arccos((l**2 + p**2 - s**2 - q**2 + 2*s*q*np.cos(alfa))/(2*l*p))
betalinha = np.arcsin((s / d) * np.sin(alfa))*180/np.pi

print(np.around(betalinha, 2))
```

Output:
[66.59 68.46 70.34 72.22 74.12 76.03 77.95 79.88 81.82 83.77 85.74 87.72
89.7  **88.29** 86.28 84.25 82.21 80.16 78.09 76.01 73.92 71.81 69.69 67.55
65.4  63.23 61.05 58.86 56.65 54.43 52.2  49.95 47.68 45.41 43.12 40.82
38.5  36.18 33.84 31.49]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the root problem is, but I believe you can correct it by

1. Computing the diff of the values (values less than the previous ones yield a negative value)
2. Multiply the diff by 2 and cumsum
3. Add that to `betalinha`

```
# Compute the diff (adding a dummy value to the beginning since diff returns an array of N - 1 length)
diff = np.insert(np.diff(betalinha), 0, 1)

# Reset positive values to 0
diff[diff > 0] = 0

# Fix decreasing values
betalinha -= diff.cumsum() * 2
```

Output:

```
>>> betalinha
array([ 66.59,  68.46,  70.34,  72.22,  74.12,  76.03,        77.95,  79.88,
        81.82,  83.77,  85.74,  87.72,  89.7 ,  91.11, <---   93.12,  95.15,
        97.19,  99.24, 101.31, 103.39, 105.48, 107.59,       109.71, 111.85,
       114.  , 116.17, 118.35, 120.54, 122.75, 124.97,       127.2 , 129.45,
       131.72, 133.99, 136.28, 138.58, 140.9 , 143.22,       145.56, 147.91])
```

Comment: Brilliant way @richardec, thank you very much! My problem with these values is that I need to sum them to other angles and calculate sin, cos, etc, and with the suplementaries I had problems in final results. It isn't in the Question to simplify and focus on my problem.

Comment: This does not work correctly. For example if `betalinha = np.array([60., 80., 70.])` it will give `[60., 80., 90.]` while it should give `[60., 80, 110.]`.

Comment: Sorry @bb1, will you please explain why it's wrong? Per the "Desirable way" in the question, it seems to correctly generate 91.66 which rounds to 91.2...or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Danilo what do you mean by "It isn't in the Question to simplify and focus on my problem."? Isn't your problem that the values are going down after 90, and you want them to keep going up?

Comment: @richardec oh I understood you were talking about what's the impact of using the suplementary instead of the angles after 90. Yes my problem is what you have written.

Comment: @richardec Unless I misunderstand the question, 88.29 should be replaced by an angle x greater than 89.7 such that sin(x) = sin(88.29). This angle is given by `88.29 + 2*(90-88.29) = 91.70`. Your code is computing instead `88.29 + 2*(89.7-88.29) = 91.11`

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try to fix that..

Comment: @richardec  an another way to fix my problem is using what I did in the other Answer. I didn't do that before because I have never used this command diff, I didn't thought in this possibility to see the suplementary angles.

Comment: Okay, well, good! Yeah, `diff` is super useful.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer -  looks good!

Answer (score 0):

```
diff = np.insert(np.diff(betalinha), 0, 1)

while j < len(diff):
    if diff[j] < 0:
        betalinha[j] -= np.pi
        betalinha[j] *= -1
    j+=1
```

Output:

```
[1.16218675, 1.19480394, 1.22758774, 1.26054302, 1.29367464,
1.32698746, 1.36048627, 1.39417585, 1.42806092, 1.46214611,
1.49643599, 1.53093502, 1.56564752, 1.60057772, 1.63572963,
1.67110713, 1.70671387, 1.74255327, 1.7786285, 1.81494244,
1.85149766, 1.88829639, 1.92534047, 1.96263135, 2.00017004,
2.03795707, 2.07599248, 2.11427574, 2.15280579, 2.19158094,
2.23059888, 2.26985664, 2.30935057, 2.34907629, 2.38902871,
2.42920199, 2.46958953, 2.51018397, 2.55097717, 2.59196023]
```